# Ruby On Rails - Showing the default option with collection_select dependent on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm using an out-dated version of rails (2.2).

I have a page which has a search filter. When I filter the options, I would like the Dropdown boxes to default to the filters I selected. The filters are being stored as parameters in the URL. i.e. *filter[Issue+Header]=test&filter[in4User]=1&filter[Module]=3*

What I search:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r804l.png

What I currently see when page loads (as you can see, text boxes are re-populated, but dropdowns are not):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G83X8.png

What I want to see when page loads:

http:// [remove_this_space] i.stack.imgur.com/r804l.png

Example of a collection_select I am using:

```
<%= collection_select(:filter, "Client", Client.find(:all, :conditions => ['status = 0']), :ClientID, :Name, :include_blank => true) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is pass in the `:selected` option into collection select, and pass the appropriate param as the value, so something like:

```
<%= collection_select(:filter, "Client", Client.find(:all, :conditions => ['status = 0']), :ClientID, :Name, :include_blank => true, :selected => params[:filter]) %>
```

That should select the client, assuming that the Client is in the collection.

Comment: Unfortunately, :selected doesn't work for me. Could this be because I am in a form_tag and not a form_for?

Comment: No, its most likely because your params[:filter] needs to contain one of the choices in the collection, it most likely doesn't.